# Trying to draw rectangles/ovals after user selects what color and shape to be drawn in Java

Tags: java, swing, draw, paintcomponent

Just started messing around with GUI. I want this program to draw rectangles/circles (depending on which the user clicks on) and keep drawing the same shape inside the previous one until it reaches the amount the user puts into the text field. When I run it, it never seems to make it to paintComponent. Thanks for any help.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

class ShapePanel extends JPanel implements ActionListener {

  JTextField numOfShapes;
  JButton square, circle, black, red, blue;
  boolean isSquare = true;
  boolean isCircle = false;
  boolean isBlack = true;
  boolean isRed = false;
  boolean isBlue = false;
  int num = 0;

 ShapePanel() {

    setLayout( new BorderLayout());

    //Panel 1
    JPanel p1 = new JPanel();
    square = new JButton("Squares");
    p1.add(square);
    square.addActionListener( this );

    circle = new JButton("Circles");
    p1.add(circle);
    circle.addActionListener( this );

    numOfShapes = new JTextField(15);
    p1.add(numOfShapes);
    //numOfShapes.addKeyListener( this );
    add(p1, BorderLayout.NORTH);



    //Panel 3
    JPanel p3 = new JPanel();
    black = new JButton("Black");
    p3.add(black);
    black.addActionListener( this );

    red = new JButton("Red");
    p3.add(red);
    red.addActionListener( this );

    blue = new JButton("Blue");
    p3.add(blue);
    blue.addActionListener( this );
    add(p3, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
    String nOfS = numOfShapes.getText();
    System.out.println("made it to action performed");

    if(ae.getSource() == square){
        isSquare = true;
    }
    if(ae.getSource() == circle){
        isCircle = true;
    }
    if(ae.getSource() == black){
        isBlack = true;
    }
    if(ae.getSource() == red){
        isRed = true;
    }
    if(ae.getSource() == blue){
        isBlue = true;
    }
}  


class Paint extends JPanel {

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        super.paintComponent(g);

        JPanel p2 = new JPanel();
        int c = 0;//change in size
        int x1 = 20;
        int x2 = 200;
        int y1 = 20;
        int y2 = 200;
        String nOfS = numOfShapes.getText(); //number of shapes to be drawn
        num = Integer.parseInt(nOfS);

        System.out.println("Made it to paint component");

        if (isBlack){
            g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            isBlack = false;
        }
        if (isRed){
            g.setColor(Color.RED);
            isRed = false;
        }
        if (isBlue){
            g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
            isBlue = false;
        }

        if (isSquare){
            for(int i = 0; i < num; i++){
                x1+=c;
                y1+=c;
                x2-=c;
                y2-=c;
                g.drawRect(x1, y1, x2, y2);
                c+=10;
            }
            isSquare = false;
        }
        if (isCircle){
            for(int i = 0; i < num; i++){
                x1+=c;
                y1+=c;
                x2-=c;
                y2-=c;
                g.drawOval(x1, y1, x2, y2);
                c+=10;
            }
            isCircle = false;
        }

        add(p2, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }
  }
}


public class lab14 {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame application = new JFrame();
    application.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    application.setSize(400, 400);
    application.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    application.setTitle("Shapes");
application.add(new ShapePanel());
    application.setVisible(true);
 }
}
```

Comment: Why are you trying to add a component in a JPanel's `paintComponent` method? I don't see how it serves any purpose in your code other than to cover over any decent painting that the code might be doing. It als defies all logic as it is something that should never be done.

Comment: You're also adding an ActionListen to the `circle` JButton ***many*** times(???)` and not at all to other buttons. Time to do a little critical reading of your code. **Edit** hell, your program's behavior should already be telling you that you're doing this -- the 4 ActionListeners all added to Circle are printing 4 times when the button is pressed. You need to be a bit more careful with your proof-reading as compilers are unforgiving.

Comment: Sorry, I've been staring at it for hours and over-looked it. Like I said before, I'm NEW to using GUI. How would I have the paint component inside a panel, since the way I'm doing it is incorrect?

Comment: You've already got the method inside of a class that extends JPanel, but you never seem to use instances of that JPanel anywhere. You need to add an instance of that class somewhere to your GUI for its paintComponent to show anything. Also, you still haven't fixed the paintComponent error that I mentioned in my first comment. Proof-reading your code has little to do with GUI coding and everything to do with taking care to avoid sloppy mistakes.

Comment: Well, I haven't fixed it because I don't know how to yet. Obviously.

Comment: To fix it -- remove it. Again it serves no purpose other than to mess you up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Recommendations

- I would rename the Paint JPanel to something else as the Paint class name is already used as one of the Java core classes. Rename it to something else, say DrawPanel.
- I'd override `paintComponent(...)` in the DrawPanel class and call the super's method, as you are doing.
- I'd get rid of any code that changes the object's state or adds components to the GUI from within `paintComponet`. It should be for painting and painting only.
- I'd add a DrawPanel instance, say called `drawPanel, to the main JPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER.
- I'd be sure to add an ActionListener to a JButton only once.
- In the ActionListener, I'd call `repaint()` on my drawPanel instance after changing its state.